# How to change values in a raster file at particular positions?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, pyqgis

I have a collection of coordinates which comes from a QGSGeometry object. The shape is a polygon.

example:

```
qgsGeometry [[(75.2172,17.6566), (75.8499,17.9613), (75.5218,17.2113), (75.2172,17.4574), (75.2172,17.5277), (75.2172,17.6566)]]
```

How can I change the values of a raster file (geotif) only at the raster cells inside of the polygon (red line in screenshot)?

I know how to transform a raster and write or update with gdal it. But I don't know how to change values only at an given area like the inside of a polygon.

[image]

Comment: do they need to be fully contained? In other words, how is "inside" defined for you? And it doesn't even look like a polygon, so that needs fixing first. Then you could intersect and update there.